# How to make R datatable buttons save to specific location

Tags: r, dt

I have been using the R Datatable package to display information for a team a work with and spit out html docs for them to use.  We are trying to find a way to add comments for all to see on the data tables, so i made the columns editable however i can't find a way to get this information to everyone.  I created a save button that would work however i can only get this to save to the downloads folder of whoever is clicking the button.  Is there a way to save this file to a public location?

Or a better way to add comments on the DT.

Here is the code im currently using:

````
---
title: "Comments Test"
output: html_document
---
#### `r format(Sys.time(), "%B %d, %Y")`

```{r echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(DT)

df <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(50), nrow=10))
df$Comments <- ""


datatable(df, extensions = c('FixedHeader', 
'ColReorder', 'Buttons'),
  options = list(
  dom = 'Blfrtip',
  buttons = list(list( extend = 'csv',
                       filename = '//public/comments/comments.csv',
                       text = 'Save')),
  autoWidth = TRUE,
  fixedHeader = TRUE,
  colReorder = TRUE),
  width = "965px", fillContainer = FALSE, escape = FALSE,
  rownames = FALSE, autoHideNavigation = FALSE, editable = TRUE)
```
````

Thank You.